# placeholder text and search icon on search box border isnt directly aligned

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make a responsive flat design search box to place it at the right side of my navigation bar (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csY6KW7cIUM&ab_channel=GeekBase), but the placeholder text and the search icon of the search box isn't aligned with the border and I'm very confused.

any help would be appreciated!

```css
.boxContainer {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: top;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 4px solid #2980b9;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.elementsContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.search {
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="logo"><a href="#">Logo.</a></div>
      <ul class="links">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team Sites</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Useful Links</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="boxContainer">
      <table class="elementsContainer">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search">
          </td>
          <td>
            <a type="submit" class="search-icon"><i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show what kind of result you actually want?

Comment: Please don't use table for layout!!

Comment: Please revise the snippet I created to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Yes, that video gives you bad advice. Tables should really only be use to display data.

Comment: @Diwyansh i'd like the search box shown in the video except it will be on a navigation bar that is responsive. i dont suppose i could attach images here can i?

Comment: @Sfili_81 oh no. any suggestions of videos i could follow?

Comment: It doesn't help to talk to me down here. _Revise your post_ to demonstrate the problem and explain. See [ask] for tips.